# Using of verbs in Noun clauses

Tags: grammar

I suggested you see a doctor.
I suggested you saw a doctor.

What is the difference between them as I know in noun clauses "that" and " should" may be omitted, but can we use "saw" after modal verb "should"?

Comment: It looks like a report of something previously said where the original utterance was either _I suggest you see a doctor_ (if said directly to me), or _I suggest that x sees a doctor_ (if said to a 3rd party). It's normal when repeating the content of what was said to 'backshift' the tense, in this case from present tense "see" to past tense "saw". If the sentiment is still valid, i.e. I didn't actually see a doctor, then you could retain the present tense "see" in your report.

Answer (score 2):

"I suggested you see a doctor." is a reported imperative.  It is  the indirect discourse counterpart of

> I suggested to you: "See a doctor!"

"I suggested you saw a doctor." is a reported declarative.  It means

> I suggested to someone that you saw a doctor.